# Firefox instance is not getting open using selenium

Tags: firefox, selenium

I tried to open Firefox instance using selenium driver but its showing me some error and some times the browser opens but the specified URL is not getting printed to the Adress bar.

Here's the code that I have written

package com.samaritan.automation;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
    class CommonFunctions   
    {  

        public void click()  
        {  
            try 
            {  
                String data;
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/eRecruiters/_Recruiters - Copy.properties"));                                                     

                while((data = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    String[] strArr = data.split("\t");
                    String url =new StringBuffer(strArr[1]).append(strArr[0]).toString();
                    System.out.println(url);
                    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

                    driver.get(url + "/");
                    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

                    driver.quit();
                }
           } 
           catch(IOException e) {  
                System.out.println("File not fould !");  
           }  
       }        
    }
```

Can someone point out what I am missing?
I have installed the latest selenium jar files and the Firefox installed on my machine22.0
Is that the problem? or is there any problem in the code?

Comment: What version of Selenium? What about other browsers?

Comment: Selenium-java-2.34.0 and Selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0 and I haven't tried on any other browser

Comment: The server is at v2.34 too, upgrade it as well: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list

Comment: I also tried that but its not working either..!! Its showing Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
*** LOG addons.manager: Application has been upgraded and then its starts updating the firefox

Comment: @Yougandhara Can you share the firefox version you are using. The code is working fine on my end. Please check the selenium standalone and firefox version compatibility.